# Phalcon Paginator Breaks Query Builder query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination, phalcon

I have been wasting too much time trying to resolve an issue regarding `Phalcon/Paginator` used with `QueryBuilder` for a particular query. The query works fine until I try adding the paginator, and it seems the paginator is breaking the query. Seeing as there is a paginator built into Phalcon, and I have used it throughout this project, it would seem wrong to get around this problem by creating a separate custom paging system just for a couple of queries! So I would like to get this to work.

Here's the builder;

```
$_ads = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->columns($dist . ' AS distance, classifieds_ads.id AS id, classifieds_ads.title AS title, classifieds_ads.description AS description, classifieds_ads.city AS city, classifieds_ads.country AS country, classifieds_ads.latitude AS latitude, classifieds_ads.longitude AS longitude, classifieds_images.file AS image')
    ->addFrom('\Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds', 'classifieds_ads')
    ->leftJoin('\Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsImages', "classifieds_images.ad_id = classifieds_ads.id", 'classifieds_images')
    ->where($where)
    ->groupBy('classifieds_ads.id')
    ->having($having)
    ->orderBy($order);
```

Here's an example of the generated query without paginator;

```
SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(****)) * cos(radians(`classifieds_ads`.`latitude`)) * cos(radians(`classifieds_ads`.`longitude`) - radians(****)) + sin(radians(****)) * sin(radians(`classifieds_ads`.`latitude`)))) AS `distance`, `classifieds_ads`.`id` AS `id`, `classifieds_ads`.`title` AS `title`, `classifieds_ads`.`description` AS `description`, `classifieds_ads`.`city` AS `city`, `classifieds_ads`.`country` AS `country`, `classifieds_ads`.`latitude` AS `latitude`, `classifieds_ads`.`longitude` AS `longitude`, `classifieds_images`.`file` AS `image` 
FROM `classifieds_ads` AS `classifieds_ads`  
LEFT JOIN `classifieds_images` AS `classifieds_images` ON `classifieds_images`.`ad_id` = `classifieds_ads`.`id` 
WHERE `classifieds_ads`.`status` = 'active' AND (`title` LIKE '%query%' OR `description` LIKE '%query%' OR `classifieds_ads`.`tags` LIKE '%query%') 
GROUP BY `id` 
HAVING `distance` <= 200 
ORDER BY IF(`title` LIKE '%query%', 1, IF(`classifieds_ads`.`tags` LIKE '%query%', 2, IF(`description` LIKE '%query%', 3, 4)))
```

This works as expected. However, when I add the paginator;

```
$paginator = new \Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\QueryBuilder(
        array(
            'builder' => $_ads,
            'limit' => 5,
            'page' => \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->getShared('request')->getQuery('page', 'int')
        )
    );
    $ads = $paginator->getPaginate();
```

This gives me an error: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064....right syntax to use near ') AS`rowcount`FROM`

The query that paginator is now generating is;

```
SELECT COUNT() AS `rowcount` 
FROM `classifieds_ads` AS `classifieds_ads` 
LEFT JOIN `classifieds_images` AS `classifieds_images` ON `classifieds_images`.`ad_id` = `classifieds_ads`.`id` 
WHERE `classifieds_ads`.`status` = 'active' AND (`classifieds_ads`.`title` LIKE '%query%' OR `classifieds_ads`.`description` LIKE '%query%' OR `classifieds_ads`.`tags` LIKE '%query%') 
HAVING `classifieds_ads`.`distance` <= 200
```

It seems that `SELECT COUNT()` is breaking the query and also the query is now incomplete! I have a feeling this could be because I have used `SELECT table.field AS xxx` in `columns()`.

I am not sure if this unexpected behaviour is a bug or maybe I'm overlooking something. Any ideas?

Comment: Check my updated answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
$_ads = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
            ->columns([
                'distance'    => $dist,
                'id'          => 'classifieds_ads.id',
                'title'       => 'classifieds_ads.title',
                'description' => 'classifieds_ads.description',
                'city'        => 'classifieds_ads.city',
                'country'     => 'classifieds_ads.country',
                'latitude'    => 'classifieds_ads.latitude',
                'longitude'   => 'classifieds_ads.longitude',
                'image'       => 'classifieds_images.file',
            ])
            ->addFrom('\Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds', 'classifieds_ads')
            ->leftJoin('\Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsImages', "classifieds_images.ad_id = classifieds_ads.id", 'classifieds_images')
            ->where($where)
            ->groupBy('classifieds_ads.id')
            ->having($having)
            ->orderBy($order);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I seem to be getting the exact same error when executing a similar query

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS `rowcount`
>   FROM `order`' at line 1

I was able to use a workaround to solve this. Instead of using the QueryBuilder as data:

```
$paginator = new Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\QueryBuilder(["builder" => $_ads, "limit" => 4, "page" => 1]);
```

I am using the resultset as data:

```
$resultset = $_ads->getQuery()->execute();
$paginator = new Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model(["data" => $resultset, "limit" => 4, "page" => 1]);
```

After further researching, there appears to be an issue when using `group by`, `QueryBuilder` and the `Paginator` together. See this [open issue in Phalcon](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2065).

Comment: @Ally, are you still having issues with this problem, or did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Thanks for your update. I got around it by using raw queries instead of query builder, and creating another paginator for those. It seems query builder & paginator are not reliable when used for anything other than fairly basic queries that don't involve multiple selects, group by's etc! I believe I have tried your method above before, but had issues with it. I may try it again some time, but query builder does seem to be very limited.

Comment: Alright @Ally, give it a try when you get to it. Don't forget to accept the answer if it eventually helped you out, so future users don't have to go through the same pains as you did ;)

Comment: Hi @Timothy, I gave it a quick go, but it didn't paginate with my setup. Pagination returned `NULL`. I can't see that it would work efficiently any way as pagination would have no control over the query, so at best it would be putting the entire results into memory then iterating through a sub-set of them, which kind of defeats the point of pagination any way. With a very large data set going into memory each time, it would cause issues. In any case, the pagination I have now setup will prevent slow downs when paging large data sets. Thanks for your efforts though!